Maximum value of $G = (x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$
Inspired by this interesting minimum value problem that I solved and got $\text{minimum } G=41$, I was curious to know what would be the maximum value of $G$. The problem can be stated as follows:
Let $x,y, z>0$ and
$$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=11$$
Find the maximum value of
$$G= (x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right).$$
I tried to solve it and got the answer. As a free knowledge enthusiast, I am happy to share my solution with the community. Any positive comments and feedback are appreciated. Interested users can also share their solutions or approaches to solve this problem.

Well done and (+1). I made it using Lagrange multipliers (a pure nightmare) and the result is for $x=1$, $y$ and $z$ being the roots of two quartic polynomials.

Let $p=(x+y+z),\ q=(xy+yz+zx),\ r=xyz$. Then,
$$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=p\cdot\frac{xy+yz+zx}{xyz}=\frac{pq}r=11\implies pq=11r\tag{1}$$
We recall algebraic identities:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)=p^2-2q\tag{2}$$
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz+(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)=3r+p(p^2-3q)=p^3-3pq+3r\tag{3}$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}=\frac{3}{xyz}+\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)\left[\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)^2-3\left(\frac{1}{xy}+\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}\right)\right]=\frac{3}{r}+\frac{q}{r}\left(\frac{q^2}{r^2}-\frac{3p}r\right)\tag{4}$$
Observation: equation $(4)$ is basically obtained from $(3)$ by $r\to\frac1r,\ p\to\frac qr$, and $q\to\frac pr$ as $x\to\frac1x,\ y\to\frac1y$, and $z\to\frac1z$.
Now,
we have
$$G=(x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)=(p^3-3pq+3r)\left(\frac{q^3}{r^3}-\frac{3pq}{r^2}+\frac3r\right)\tag{5}$$
Substituting $pq=11r$ and simplifying for $G$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}G&=(p^3-30r)\left(\frac{q^3}{r^3}-\frac{30}r\right)\\&=\frac{p^3q^3}{r^3}-\frac{30p^3}r-\frac{30q^3}{r^2}+900\\&=11^3+900-30\left(\frac{p^3}r+\frac{q^3}{r^2}\right)\\&\leq2231-30\cdot2\sqrt{\frac{p^3}{r}\cdot\frac{q^3}{r^2}}\qquad\text{(AM–GM inequality)}\\&=2231-60\sqrt{11^3}\\G_\text{max}&=2231-660\sqrt{11}\approx42.027638\end{aligned}$$
Hence, the maximum value of $G$ is $\boxed{2231-660\sqrt{11}\approx42.027638}$.
I hope you like it.

Interesting. However, you should prove that there exists the positive $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $G = G_ {\max}$, if not, $G_ {\max}$ cannot be reached.
